# Google Cloud Platform - cannot apply DNS forwarding policy

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to configure an outbound DNS Forwarding Policy within a VPC as described in the [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/overview#dns-forwarding-zones).  However, when applying a newly added DNS Fowarding Policy by hitting the save button on the VPC profile edit page, I get an alert message with a very generic "Unknown Error" message.

Here are some screenshots that illustrate.  I have tried this on two different VPCs in 2 different projects and get the same error.

[image: policy editor]

[image: policy saving]

[image: alert error]

Has anyone encountered this type of generic error?  What's the best way to show this to GCP engineers?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to show a screenshot of the Routes tab for your VPC?

Comment: The "Unknown error" could have appeared when your session was terminated. Have you tried to reload the GCP Console web page with "Ctrl+F5" at the beginning to make sure your authentication is still alive?